# Codigo VBA Excel mayúscula de inicio

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy comenzando con lo que es VBA y tengo hartos problemas para entender la programación, tengo un código que no puedo hacer funcionar con lo que deseo, este es:

```
Function Test(NamesRng As Range) As String
Dim ultimo As String
Dim cp As String
Dim conjunto() As String
conjunto = Split(Cell.Value)

ultimo = NamesRng(NamesRng.Rows.Count + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Value
For Each Cell In NamesRng
    If cp = "" Then
        cp = StrConv(Cell.Value, vbProperCase)
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Cell) And Cell.Value <> "" Then
        If Cell.Value = ultimo Then
            cp = cp & " y " & Cell.Value & "."
        Else
            cp = cp & ", " & Cell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next Cell

Test = cp
End Function
```

Lo que estoy intentando arreglar o hacer, es que la primera letra de un conjunto de palabras se marque como mayúscula, actualmente la frase aparece de esta manera:

> Hola Mundo Que Tal

Pero necesito que aparezca como:

> Hola mundo que tal

Si pudieran ayudarme con esto seria de muchísima ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pásalo todo a minúscula y luego simplemente pasa a mayúscula la primera letra.

Answer (score 2):

A ver que te parece

El código sería para sustituir totalmente al tuyo

Lo único que tendrías que hacer, sería enlazar el código con tu excel en la celda activa o darle tu la dirección de la celda donde tienes el texto y utilizar luego la variable miFrase para pegarla en la celda donde deseas visualizar el texto formateado

Veamos:
creas un nuevo módulo en tu libro y pegas el siguiene código:

```
Sub metodoPrimeraLetraMayuscula()
    'declaramos una variable longitud de tipo Byte
    Dim longitud As Byte
    'declaramos dos variables String, una para la frase y otra para el resultado de la transformación (miFrase) será el resultado
    Dim frase As String, miFrase As String
    'la frase puede ser el contenido de una o varias celdas concatenadas
    frase = Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(7, 5).Value
    'obtenemos la longitud de la frase y le restamos 1 caracter
    longitud = Len(frase) - 1
    'Ponemos en mayúscula el primer carácter de la frase, y el resto en minúscula
    miFrase = StrConv(Left(frase, 1), vbUpperCase) & StrConv(Mid(frase, 2, longitud), vbLowerCase)
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(9, 5).Value = miFrase
End Sub
```

Añades un segundo módulo y pegas éste otro código:

```
'creamos el botón boton1, que abre el formulario
Sub Botón1_Haga_clic_en()
    Load FormateaTexto
    FormateaTexto.Show
End Sub
'creamos el botón boton3 que recoge los datos de la hoja en las celdas Cells(7, 5) y Cells(9, 5)
Sub Botón3_Haga_clic_en()
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(7, 5).Value = ""
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(9, 5).Value = ""
End Sub
'creamos el botón boton4, que ejecuta el método de formateo del texto
Sub Botón4_Haga_clic_en()
    metodoPrimeraLetraMayuscula
End Sub
```

Em el libro, de excel, en la Hoja1 (o puedes crear una nueva y renombrarla si no la tienes, o renombrar la hoja en el código), tienes ue crear tres botones de acción botón1, botón3 y botón4

Prueba a descargarte el ejemplo:

https://github.com/eltrasgu/Programas/blob/main/FormateaTexto.xlsm

**EDITADO**

Prueba a ver ahora. Lo que hago, es simplemente concatenar las celdas que utilizo y cambiar la forma de referenciarlas. En éste caso E7, G7, I7, K7, M7

```
Sub metodoPrimeraLetraMayuscula()
    Sheets("Hoja1").Activate
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    'declaramos una variable longitud de tipo Byte
    Dim longitud As Byte
    'declaramos dos variables String, una para la frase y otra para el resultado de la transformación (miFrase) será el resultado
    Dim frase As String, miFrase As String
    'Evaluamos que las celdas no esten vacías
    'Si la celda E7 no está vacía mete su contenido en la variable frase
    If (Range("E7").Text <> "") Then
        frase = Range("E7").Text
    End If
    'Si la celda G7 no está vacía agrega su contenido en la variable frase
    If (Range("G7").Text <> "") Then
        frase = frase & " " & Range("G7").Text
    End If
    'Si la celda I7 no está vacía agrega su contenido en la variable frase
    If (Range("I7").Text <> "") Then
        frase = frase & " " & Range("I7").Text
    End If
    'Si la celda K7 no está vacía agrega su contenido en la variable frase
    If (Range("K7").Text <> "") Then
        frase = frase & " " & Range("K7").Text
    End If
    'Si la celda M7 no está vacía agrega su contenido en la variable frase
    If (Range("M7").Text <> "") Then
        frase = frase & " " & Range("M7").Text
    End If

    'obtenemos la longitud de la frase y le restamos 1 caracter
    longitud = Len(frase) - 1
    'Ponemos en mayúscula el primer carácter de la frase, y el resto en minúscula
    miFrase = StrConv(Left(frase, 1), vbUpperCase) & StrConv(Mid(frase, 2, longitud), vbLowerCase)
    'Una vez formateado el texto, lo pegamos en el rango de celdas de la Fila 9, columna 5, o sea E9:M9
    Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(9, 5).Value = miFrase
End Sub
```

Prueba ahora a ver si te sirve, sino me dices en que parte no te funciona, o que es lo que no puedes agregar a tu código.

Comment: Hola, la verdad no sabría como aplicar el código que me has entregado al que ya tengo, ya que el mío tiene además un separador con comas e "y"

Comment: Hola, intente usar tu código, sin embargo no puedo llevarlo a una función, mira lo que pasa es esto, tengo una columna con varias celdas, algunas vacías y otras no, necesito una función que acepte todas las celdas, y en las que tengan texto, que las formatee de la manera ya explicada. Intento editar tu código a función pero no me da resultados.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta y te puse un añadido para agregar varias celdas y validar que éstas tengan algún dato. A ver si te sirve